# Adding a constant to the x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

I use python and want to make a heatmap with 1900 to 2000 on the x-axis. So I have a two dimensional function, say f(t,x), where t is between 1900 and 2000. Then I define g(x)= [f(t,x) for t in range(1900,2000)] and put everything in an array by z=numpy.array([g(x) for x in range(50)]). Then I plot the heatmap by pylab.color(z), but then I lose my dependency on years, because it is now in an array which start at zero. The x-axis is then from 0 to 100. How can I add 1900 to the x-axis, not in the label, but such that the range becomes 1900-2000.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share some code to elucidate what you're doing. A working sample would help as well.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Is this good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `pcolormesh` (or `pcolor`, but `pcolormesh` is faster), you'll need to pass in explicit `x` and `y` arrays as well as your `z` array.

If you're using `imshow`, you'll need to use the `extent` kwarg.

As an example of using `pcolormesh` or `pcolor`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z = np.arange(40).reshape(4, 10)
x = np.linspace(1900, 2000, 10)
y = np.linspace(20, 50, 4)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap='gist_earth')
plt.show()
```

[image]

As an example of using `imshow` (Note that you'd need to use `aspect='auto'` as well to make `imshow` and `pcolormesh` match exactly):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z = np.arange(40).reshape(4, 10)
x = np.linspace(1900, 2000, 10)
y = np.linspace(20, 50, 4)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(z, cmap='gist_earth', interpolation='nearest', origin='lower',
          extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Now I have white spaces on the right and top again. In the previous case (with 0-100 on the x-axis) I erased it by plt.gca().set_xlim((0,100)), however in this case this does not work.

Comment: @Henry -  Typically, you'd use `ax.axis('tight')` to set the axes limits to the range of the data.  Depending on exactly what you're doing, it might make more sense to do it other ways, though.  For example, `ax.margins(some_percentage)` to add a bit of padding to the limits, `ax.set(xlim=[xmin, xmax], ylim=[ymin, ymax])` to manually set the limits, `ax.axis('image')` to use `imshow`-like axis limits, and several others.

Comment: Thanks for your help!